# How to declare both ES6 and CommonJS exports in TypeScript using Rollup?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, commonjs, es6-modules

**TL;DR**: how can I have my declaration file declare that MyModule is the `default` export when importing it as a ES6 module, but that it is the `module.exports` object when importing as commonjs?

---

I am using Rollup to bundle my module so that it can be imported both as a commonjs and an ES6 module.

```
// rollup.config.js
import ts from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/bundle.js",
      format: "cjs"
    },
    {
      file: "dist/bundle.es.js",
      format: "es"
    }
  ],
  plugins: [ts({ clean: true })]
};
```

and in my package.json:

```
 // package.json
 { ...
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "module": "dist/bundle.es.js",
 ... }
```

This is my module itself:

```
// src/index.ts
class MyModule {...}
export default MyModule;
```

Now, I can successfully import this module both by `require`ing it and `import`ing it:

```
// otherFile.js
import MyModule from 'MyModule'; // works as expected

const MyModule = require('MyModule'); // also works as expected
```

However although both ways of importing my module work as expected, *Intellisense* only works when I `import` the module, ES6 style. I assume this is because the declaration file only says `export default MyModule` and so VS Code thinks that the MyModule class is present at `require('MyModule').default`, even though it is in fact located at `require('MyModule')`.

TL;DR: how can I have my declaration file declare that MyModule is the default export when importing it as a ES6 module, but that it is the `module.exports` object when importing as commonjs?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah I really want to know too.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work in my case.

``
export default MyModule;
exports['default'] = MyModule;
module.exports = exports['default'];
``